# $.inArray deep search

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a json file like this:

```
{
    items: 
        [{  id: 1,
            catalog: {
                supplier: {
                    priority: 1
                },
            }
        },
        {   id: 2,
            catalog: {
                supplier: {
                    priority: 3
                },
            }
        },
        {   id: 3,
            catalog: {
                supplier: {
                    priority: 1
                },
            }
        }]
```

Now I want to use the $.inArray function to make a deep search of the items array.
For example all items whose catalog/supplier/priority is 1.

Something like this:

```
$.inArray(1, data.items(.catalog.supplier.priority)) > -1
```

How do I accomplish this kind of deep search?

Comment: `$.inArray` does not support JSON array. I think 

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use $.grep as well:

```js
var data = {
    items: 
        [{  id: 1,
            catalog: {
                supplier: {
                    priority: 1
                },
            }
        },
        {   id: 2,
            catalog: {
                supplier: {
                    priority: 3
                },
            }
        },
        {   id: 3,
            catalog: {
                supplier: {
                    priority: 1
                },
            }
        }]
 };
 
 var arr = jQuery.grep(data.items, function( a ) {
  return a.catalog.supplier.priority >1;
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution using Javascript.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <style>
    div {
      color: blue;
    }

    span {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <span></span>

  <script>
    var arr = {
      items: [{
          id: 1,
          catalog: {
            supplier: {
              priority: 1
            },
          }
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          catalog: {
            supplier: {
              priority: 3
            },
          }
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          catalog: {
            supplier: {
              priority: 1
            },
          }
        }
      ]
    };
    var $spans = $("span");

    var results = [];
    for (var i=0 ; i < arr.items.length ; i++)
    {
        if (arr.items[i].catalog.supplier.priority === 1) {
            results.push(arr.items[i]);
        }
    }

    $spans.eq(0).text(JSON.stringify(results));
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```